# Reading Matrix Simulink Robot Arm

Tags: matrix, simulink

I am building the trajectory of a robot arm and I have computed the position of the degrees of freedom in matrix format, i.e. the first position is row 1 of the matrix `(x1,y1,z1)`, the 2nd position is row 2 `(x2,y2,z2)` etc.

I am trying to read a row at a time in Simulink and change to the following row when the first position has been reached. However it is not possible for me to solve this with a script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly you have a matrix of desired states and some sort of control loop inside of Simulink.

In brief, loops in Simulink are best represented by switches. And the easiest way to access individual rows of your matrix of desired states (x,y,z) is through the "Select Rows" block.

For example you can feed your matrix into the "Select Rows" simulink block "In1". Then you can take the difference (using sum block) between the output of the the "Select Rows" block and your current state (x,y,z) and feed the norm of this difference into a compare block set to "less than". Feed the result of the compare block into a switch so that the switch will be thrown on when the result of the compare block is less than some tolerance. The switch can be set to 0 when False and 1 + the previous output value of the switch when True. The output value of this switch can then be used to choose the index on the "row selector."

You might encounter a scenario in which the switch will stay true for too long in which case you can either reduce your tolerance or create your own transient switch by using an AND gate to the TRUE input to switch.